# Magento Collection remove category filter

Tags: magento

I am over writing the product list in my extension but when I write the collection it add extra filter of category that i dont need.

Here is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
           ->addMinimalPrice()
           ->addFinalPrice()
           ->addTaxPercents()
           ->addStoreFilter();

$collection->addIdFilter($result);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->printlogquery(true);
```

You can see i did not add any category filter check but when i print the query i got this:

```
    SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
           `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`,
           LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`),
           `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`,
           `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, 
           `price_index`.`tier_price`,
           `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`
      FROM `mage_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
        ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
       AND price_index.website_id = '1'
       AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
        ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
       AND cat_index.store_id='1'
       AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4)
       AND cat_index.category_id='3'
     WHERE (e.entity_id in ('724', '729', '733', '737', '741', '745', '749', '755',
                            '759', '766', '770', '775', '780', '785', '920', '921',
                            '923', '927', '957', '958', '959', '960', '961', '962',
                            '963', '964', '965', '966', '967', '1146', '1147', '1185', 
                            '1186', '1187', '1188', '1189', '1190', '1191', '1192', 
                            '1193', '1194', '1195', '1196', '1274', '1275', '1276', 
                            '1277', '1278', '1279', '1280', '1281', '1282', '1283', 
                            '1284', '1285', '1286', '1287', '1288', '1289', '1290', 
                            '1291', '1292', '1293', '1294', '1295', '1310', '1311', 
                            '1312', '1313', '1314', '1315'))
```

Here you see that in query it is printing the `cat_index.category_id='3'` which i dont need. I need to know that how can i remove this category filter there?

Comment: That category filter is related to the categories for that store.

Comment: That's not what I'd call a Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: @ShaunOReilly so how can i remove that category filter?

Comment: @Tichodroma what you need me to do with this? Can u plz guide?

Comment: @ShaunOReilly when i manually run this query and remove this line cat_index.category_id='3' i got the exactly what i needed.

Comment: Can you remove the store filter then? @Mike Potter gave you the correct answer too, as the addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection method will get the list of Visible Categories, and then adds it to the select statement.

Comment: Can it possible to remove mage_catalog_product_index_price from collection ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category filter is added when you use

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Instead, remove that line, and replace it with:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) ));
```